# Train a custom model (Smart Reply)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Im using pre-trained models (smart reply) TensorFlow Lite, but it supports only the English language, i wanted to create a custom model with a different language, i have already my own dataSet.

Comment: i think the question it s clear! how to create a new model like smart reply i didn t find anything in the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the concept of transfer learning.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: how to organize my dataSet?
it is the same model architecture? 
the link you just posted he talk about Image not text

Comment: @aladin The idea with transfer learning is to use the same model, but retrain with new data. You could also alter layers in the model for your specific usecase. The concept is not exclusive for images.